# What information can be discerned about street-side power transformers just by looking at them?

Tags: power, transformer, power-engineering, power-grid

I am new, and delighted, to be part of this stack.

I was just wondering from the two images of power transformers shown below what specifications can be gleaned from their outward appearance alone?

With my extremely limited knowledge in the field, I think I may be correct when presuming they're both three-phase transformers (evident from the number of high-voltage bushings)? If so, what other information about them (type, purpose, e.g. step-up, step-down) can I get from these photos alone, and how?

[image: image 1][image: image 2]

Comment: The writing on that first one presumably means something, though I couldn't tell you what. It doesnt' look like it's just graffiti though.

Comment: On the first one there appears to be a QR code on a label. From the picture can't make out the contents of the label, but might be a manufacturers part number. On the second one might also be a rating plate on the side, but again from the picture can't read the details.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I could try get a closer, zoomed-in photo, but have been warned about the attractive field they generate so I'm kind of hesitant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andy says, transformers will have data plates on them. However actually reading those data plates may be difficult. They are likely to be faded and dirty and you are unlikely to be able to get particularly close to them without violating safety rules.

A rule of thumb is that a voltage of x volts is suitable for distribution over distances of up to roughly x meters. Beyond that volt drop becomes a major PITA. However high voltages also have problems, they need thicker insulation on cables or taller poles and larger insulators for overhead bare wires.

So the electricity transmission and distribution grid steps down in stages, from hundreds of kilovolts on the major inter-city lines to hundreds of volts at final utilisation. The exact voltages will vary by country and application.

The transformers in your pictures are clearly 3 phase and their purpose is clearly to provide the last step down* before power is delivered from the distribution network to the end user.

On the first transformer we can also see the output wiring. There are four conductors on the output which strongly suggests that the output is wired in a star (wye) configuration. The voltage will likely depend on where in the world you are. On the second transformer we can't see the output wiring in the picture.

The exact voltages involved will depend on where in the world you are. Here in the UK the input to a transformer like that would typically be 6.6KV or 11KV and the secondary would almost certainly be wired for 230V phase to neutral and 400V phase to phase. In north America voltages vary more, but if that transformer is in an apartment building then it's likely it's output is 120V phase to neutral and 208V phase to phase.

* Of course with the rise of distributed generation, the power flow through said transformers may sometimes run "backwards". So a nominally step-down transformer may sometimes act as a step-up transformer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where I'm located (Peru) they operate on 220 V and 60 Hz. I have plenty to learn on this subject, and it doesn't bode well that I had to start off by look up the acronym PITA! : P

Answer (score 1):

> *I was just wondering from the two images of power transformers shown
> below what specifications can be gleaned from their outward appearance
> alone?*

Well, if you'd taken a better photograph of the transformer information plate: -

[image]

...you'd have been over-powered with useful information.

<sub>Did you know there are also three other transformers in the clipped picture above?</sub>

Same story with the other picture: -

[image]

Read the transformer information plate to find out what it does.

> *what other information about them (type, purpose, e.g. step-up,
> step-down) can I get from these photos alone, and how?*

Nothing of much use to an electrical engineer (this is an EE site BTW).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to not become literally over-powered when taking a closer snapshot (I probably need a better camera!). I did not know those three boxes were also transformers! Lastly, what would be the appropriate stack exchange to have posted this question on? Thanks for your time.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to find out. If you are looking for EE information about them then sure, this is the site.. BTW the three little boxes are called current transformers.

Comment: So, save for the plate, there is not much electrical engineering information that can obtained from its visible structure? And in this case is the purpose of the Current Transformers to monitor the current in the residential circuit?

Comment: It looks like secondary side current monitoring but, who can say if it’s a residential circuit?

Comment: That image I took, and it's of the transformer sat behind a locked enclosure in the basement of a block of apartments where I currently reside. The second image is a transformer next to a residential complex which I visit in another part of the country.

Comment: Is it a step-down transformer?

Comment: It's either a step-down transformer or a step-up transformer. This cannot be established from the picture alone. It would be an assumption to believe that primary power comes in from the top but, it would also be an assumption that primary power comes from the lower voltage connections (those with current transformers). So, both possibilities exist.